# hg: commit a changeset as a merge

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial

Suppose I have two branches A and B. These two branches have been merged together outside of hg (manually I suppose). The merge itself is correct and the files exactly reflect the merge between branch A and B.

Is there a way to commit those files as a merge? I mean to make them appear in hg as if they were merged using hg and make the new commit have both branches as a parent?

Comment: I may have found a possible solution myself:
1) update my working copy to branch A
2) copied the merged files into the working directory
3) run "hg debugsetparents branchA branchB"
4) commit

Seems to work for me. I don't know if there are other possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do the merge, but tell hg that you really want that merge to fail. Then reset the files to the version you want and manually mark them as resolved.

```
hg -y merge --tool=internal:fail otherBranch
hg revert --all --rev thisBranch
hg resolve -a -m
```

Once you commit and you should be on your way.

See more details [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge)

Comment: Nice. I was missing the "revert" part in my attempt. That should do the trick, thanks! It should result in the same as "debugsetparent", but less "debuggy" and more "standard", I guess.